# Position element at bottom of parent

Tags: css

Does anyone know of a clean, cross browser way of positioning elements at the base of their parent, without resorting to absolute positioning?

i.e. I would like the pink and orange blocks in this example http://jsfiddle.net/27kwE/21/ to sit at the bottom of the square, not the top.

Thanks

Comment: If answer with `vertical-align` does not satisfy You, consider adding a third `div` with height equal to `200` to push the two other `div` elements down.

Comment: Yep sorry it would have if I was using pixels all around (I've just updated the example to use %) - this also means that this isn't possible as the exact height depends on the users screen.

Comment: You should explain a bit more about what you need.  What is the purpose of this arrangement?  Perhaps there's an easier way to get what you need with a different approach.

Comment: Why not `position` you say? It looks like the choice to me :)

Comment: @skip405 The specific scenario is quite complex and doesn't lend itself to absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:bottom;
```

to the container CSS.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/27kwE/9/)**

Comment: That's not going to work well if he wants there to be stuff above it.

Comment: @DragoonWraith - is that what his question asked for?

Comment: It's not, but it's pretty likely that it is what he actually wants. I didn't down-vote, I just added a comment.

Comment: @DragoonWraith - nobody said you downvoted me. And I've answered enough questions where I try not to assume what the OP wants and base my answers on what they've asked. If my answer doesn't fit becuase they've left out detail, the OP can update the question and I can revise my answer. Great system they have here.

Comment: This does work so is technically correct, but doesn't work on my real world example which is a little more complex. My container in my real world example actually is a percentage and this solution doesn't work in that case http://jsfiddle.net/27kwE/21/